# Does the Conscrypt library work with Java 11?

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, tls1.2, jetty-9

Does the Conscrypt library (https://github.com/google/conscrypt), work with Java 11? I know that it supports JDK 8 and 9, but has anyone tried it out with JDK 11? This is needed in a new project I am working on, using Java 11, in which I need to leverage Conscrypt's SSL / TLS features.

Comment: It says OpenJDK 7 or later on that page. However, I agree that more explicit testing would be required for an answer. There is still not that much deprecated in Java (up to 11), so if it is compatible is up to two things: class compatibility and compatibility of the native lib loading. Both are not likely a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this project isn't build on the JPMS.
What this means is, yes, it will work in a Java 11 environment, and it will be "transformed" to an **automatic module**.

The fact that you state it already works in a Java 9 context make it even more clear it will work in a Java 11 environment too.